# Replace #N/A from query results google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following query that is functioning fine.  However at there will be results for example a future date where the query will not have results "Query completed with an empty output.".  I'd like to replace the #N/A with 0 if possible.

Thank you in advance.

Sample Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GvH5Nyeg447_STTMgYj9VeLdwo7Mi2TnIWodbJOX3zw/edit#gid=0

=Query('Balance History'!B:O,"Select H WHERE G = '"&E2&"' and M = '"&B2&"' and N = '"&C2&"' ORDER BY O DESC Limit 1",0)

Comment: access denied to your spreadsheet, pls give permission  to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IFERROR(Query('Balance History'!B:O,"Select H WHERE G = '"&E2&"' and M = '"&B2&"' and N = '"&C2&"' ORDER BY O DESC Limit 1",0),0)
```

Comment: Sorry I updated to share the sheet 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GvH5Nyeg447_STTMgYj9VeLdwo7Mi2TnIWodbJOX3zw/edit?usp=sharing